# Zoom image button must be clicked twice to work in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a zoom button that uses getElementById to increase the width

```
<span tslbutton (click)="zoomIn()"> <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

```
zoomIn() {
    if (document.getElementById("left_pane").style.width == "25%") {
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.width = "47%"
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("left_pane").style.width == "47%") {
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.width = "100%"
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.marginRight = "0"
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.marginLeft = "0"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.width = "25%"
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.marginRight = "285px"
      document.getElementById("left_pane").style.marginLeft = "222px"
    }
  }
```

This code here displays a magnifying glass, then upon clicking it it will increase the size of my left pane on the screen.

Only issue here is that I have to click the magnifying glass image twice in order for it to zoom in. Why is this happening? And is there a way to make it zoom in on the first click? Is there a more elegant way to make this work?

Comment: If you're using Angular then you should not be manipulating the DOM directly.

Comment: What's an alternative?

Comment: Move those style properties to a CSS rule and toggle a CSS class via Angular's Virtual DOM.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean in more detail in an answer?

Comment: No, sorry - I won't. I'm not in the mood to.

Comment: Okay well if your mood changes feel free to answer. Lol.

Comment: I just try to make a snippet and for me it works. It well changes. But there is 2 things to don't forget: at begin, the width is empty, then the second time (when it's a 25%) the margin isn't changed, only the size. Which -in the case of the snippet- doesn't change something. [Here](https://hastebin.com/rikivuyiru.http) what I made